# How alter only the phone numbers in a div's content that aren't already links?

Tags: javascript, regex, dom

I need to find all the phone numbers in the `textContent` of a `div` and all its children and if they're not already made into links (e.g. by iOS Safari, or by the person who created the page's content), then make them into links. I'm not sure how to find the phone number and find if it's already a link.

The code I was using only allows for finding phone numbers in the `innerHTML` and wrapping in a link tag:

```
div.innerHTML = div.innerHTML.replace( 
    /(\(\d{3}\)(-|\.)?\d{3}(-|\.)?\d{4}|\d{3}(-|\.)?\d{3}(-|\.)?\d{4}|[0-9]{10,10})/g,
    "<a href=\"tel:$1\">$1</a>"
);
```

but how do I figure out if it's wrapped in a link tag and skip it if it is?

Answer (score 1):

How about this.

```
((\(\d{3}\)(-|\.)?\d{3}(-|\.)?\d{4}|\d{3}(-|\.)?\d{3}(-|\.)?\d{4}|[0-9]{10,10}))(?!["<])
```

That does a lookahead at the end to make sure that the next characters are not a quotation mark (like the href phone number), or a less than (like the end of your anchor tag).

Comment: This will not convert phone numbers that are surrounded by `<b>` tags, which is incorrect. But altering your end search to the `</a>` closing tag might work

Answer (score 1):

I solved it by adding a check at the end for the closing `a` tag or a quote (so it doesn't change the hrefs):

```
(?![\s]*(\<\/a>|"|'))
```

The whole regex:

```
/(\(\d{3}\)(-|\.)?\d{3}(-|\.)?\d{4}|\d{3}(-|\.)?\d{3}(-|\.)?\d{4}|[0-9]{10,10})(?![\s]*(\<\/a>|"|'))/g
```

It also allows for white space between the phone number and closing tag.